# How to prevent list from re-rendering old items when push new items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I am using a v-for to display a list on screen and a button to push some new Items on the list

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in contentList" :key="'content' + index" >
    {{ $textFormat.formatText(item) }}
</div>
<div class="btn" @click="pushitem">CLICK</div>

pushitem () {
  const self = this
  self.contentList.push(...self.newItems)
},

mounted () {
    const self = this
    self.contentList = []
    self.newItems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}
```

I am also have written a plugin to format the text on screen

```
const TextFormat = {


install (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$textFormat = {
      formatText (value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(value)
          return value
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
export default TextFormat
```

My problem is whenever i CLICK to add new items, Vue seems to re-render all items inside the v-for, therefor my formatText plugin is called again on every items, for a larger number of item on the list, the performance is worse. So is there any solution that my Plugin is only run for new items each time I click on pushItem button, but not the old one? Or is that right in the way i created the format text Plugin?

Comment: Please try computed methods maybe it will help in this scenario.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal Thank for your suggestion. I trying to use vue filter but I need to call the filter again when the window is resized. Totally stuck at that stage